# DataTables JSON Parsing Error - Access Denied

Tags: mysql, json, datatables

OK, I'll try to keep this short and to the point.

The error can be seen at http://www.hunterpdx.com/metro_new_copy/view-reports-test.php.

I am using DataTables-1.9.4 locally and everything works fine, but once uploaded to my host server, I receive the oh so popular JSON parsing error:

> DataTables warning (table id = 'example'): DataTables warning: JSON
>   data from server could not be parsed. This is caused by a JSON
>   formatting error.

I have read so many of these on here and found a TON of great advice; primarily how to pinpoint the issue. I have reviewed the Network tab on Chrome's dev tools and determined that the problem is simple:

> Warning: mysql_pconnect() [function.mysql-pconnect]: Access denied for
>   user 'username'@'localhost' (using password: NO) in
>   /home/metros9/public_html/hunterpdx.com/metro_new_copy/server_processing.php
>   on line 50
>
> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by
>   (output started at
>   /home/metros9/public_html/hunterpdx.com/metro_new_copy/server_processing.php:50)
>   in
>   /home/metros9/public_html/hunterpdx.com/metro_new_copy/server_processing.php
>   on line 42 Could not open connection to server

It seems to me that the answer should be simple: either the username or password are incorrect.  My confusion (and question) comes from the fact that it works great locally, but not live.  I am using the same database connection information for multiple MySQL queries on my live site using a db.php file, but for some reason it isn't accepting the same information from server_processing.php.  Can anyone tell me why?  I'm new, but pretty handy at figuring things out...even a general direction on something else to look for would be greatly appreciated!

server_processing.php

/* Database connection information */

```
$gaSQL['user']       = "*****";
$gaSQL['password']   = "*****";
$gaSQL['db']         = "*****";
$gaSQL['server']     = "localhost";



/* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *
 * If you just want to use the basic configuration for DataTables with PHP server-side, there is
 * no need to edit below this line
 */

/* 
 * Local functions
 */
function fatal_error ( $sErrorMessage = '' )
{
    header( $_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'] .' 500 Internal Server Error' );
    die( $sErrorMessage );
}


/* 
 * MySQL connection
 */
if ( ! $gaSql['link'] = mysql_pconnect( $gaSql['server'], $gaSql['user'], $gaSql['password']  ) )
{
    fatal_error( 'Could not open connection to server' );
}

if ( ! mysql_select_db( $gaSql['db'], $gaSql['link'] ) )
{
    fatal_error( 'Could not select database ' );
}
```

Comment: May be that user doesn't have privileges in database.check that user privileges in database

Comment: That's a good start, but I thought the same thing; I've already verified that the user has full privileges. I also created a second user with a different username and password, also with full privileges; still no good.

Comment: Hold the phones!  It works now!  ...AND I'm an idiot - it really was simple: capitalization issue on the variable names; set as gaSQL and called as gaSql...I feel very foolish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Variables were set to gaSQL and then were being called as gaSql - capitalization inconsistencies!

Knew it would be easy, but kicking myself for how long it took to see the answer.